# Application of ZMT to birational maps in Milne's Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation, affine-varieties, birational-geometry

I'm studying Algebraic Geometry from this [book](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf). At page 187 the author proves that

> If $\varphi:W\to V$
> is a regular birational quasi-finite map between irreducible varieties and $V$ is normal, then $\varphi$ is an open immersion.

I understand many bits of this proof but I fail to grasp some fundamental steps.

**My attempt of grasping the proof**

Since $\varphi$ is a quasi-finite regular map, we can factor it thanks to ZMT (Zariski's Main Theorem)

$$W\overset{j}\hookrightarrow V'\overset{\varphi'}\to V $$

Since a finite morphism is an affine morphism I can cover $V$ with open affine sets $U$ so that $\varphi':\varphi'^{-1}(U)\to U$ is a finite morphism. This means that the extension $k[U]\hookrightarrow k[\varphi'^{-1}(U)]$ is integral. Now comes the first unclear step:

*This means that $k[\varphi'^{-1}(U)]$ is the integral closure of $k[U]$ in $k(W)$.*

***Just... why? Why an integral extension is automatically the integral closure?***

Moving along with the proof $k[\varphi'^{-1}(U)]$ is the integral closure of $k[U]$ in $k(W)$ and $k(W)=k(V)$ because $\varphi$ is birational. Now another step that I don't understand

*Since $V$ is normal $k[U]$ is integrally closed in $k(V)$.*

***Every affine open set of a normal variety is normal so I agree that $k[U]$ is integrally closed in $k(U)$. But why in $k(V)$?***

Moving along with the proof, since $k[U]$ is integrally closed in $k(V)$ and $k[\varphi'^{-1}(U)]$ is the integral closure of $k[U]$ in $k(V)$ we have that $k[U]=k[\varphi'^{-1}(U)]$ so $U$ is isomorphic to $\varphi'^{-1}(U)$. Now comes the last step that I don't understand.

*This proves that $V$ is isomorphic to $V'$ and this concludes the proof.*

***I think that we only proved that $V$ and $V'$ are "locally isomorphic". And even assuming that $V\cong V'$, how does this conclude the proof exactly?***

Comment: I think you mean “Zariski’s Main Theorem”… For 1), see the last sentence of the statement of Theorem 8.45. For 2), don’t you have $k(U)=k(V)$? For 3), I suspect that you didn’t just prove that $V’$ and $V$ were “locally isomorphic”. You probably actually proved that $\varphi’$ was, locally on the base, an isomorphism. Then $\varphi’$ would be an actual isomorphism and $\varphi=\varphi’ \circ j$ would be an open immersion.

Comment: @Aphelli Yes I meant Zariski. Thank you: this clarifies the last two points. Do you know how to help me on the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m turning my comment into an answer.

For your first question, you are right: there is *a priori* no reason why $k[\varphi’^{-1}(U)]$ should be the integral closure of $k[U]$ in $k(W)$. The answer lies in the last sentence of Theorem 8.45, which gives an explicit factorization in this setting.

For your second question, note that $k(U)=k(V)$.

For your third question, I am less certain, because I didn’t read the entire proof. What seems most likely is that you don’t actually prove that $V’$ and $V$ are locally isomorphic (which wouldn’t imply anything, of course), but that $\varphi’: V’ \rightarrow V$ is an isomorphism locally on the base.

If this is the case, it then follows that $\varphi’$ is an actual isomorphism and thus that $\varphi=\varphi’ \circ j$ is an open immersion.